# Showing the path of image instead of image in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to fetch data from Product table and assigning to a row and then row to a table and then finally table to GridView.The images are in the images folder and in database column I am storing the path of the images. But instead of showing the actual image it shows only the path.Here is the code for code

```
public partial class prac3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    List<String> pn = new List<String>();
    List<Int32> pp = new List<Int32>();
       List<Int32> dp=new List<Int32>();
       List<String> pic = new List<String>();
       List<Image> pic1 = new List<Image>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getdata();
    }

    private void getdata()
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString))
        {
            int k=0;

            con.Open();



            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Product ", con);

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        DataTable tb = new DataTable();
                        tb.Columns.Add("id1");
                        tb.Columns.Add("id2");
                        tb.Columns.Add("id3");


                        while (reader.Read())
                        {

                            DataRow dr1 = tb.NewRow();
                           DataRow dr2 = tb.NewRow();
                            DataRow dr3 = tb.NewRow();
                            DataRow dr4 = tb.NewRow();

                           pn.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["productName"]));
                          pp.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["productPrice"]));
                          dp.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["discountedPrice"]));
                         pic.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["productImage"]));

                            k++;
                            if(k==3)
                            {


                                k = 0;
                                dr1["id1"] = pn.ElementAt(0);
                                dr1["id2"] = pn.ElementAt(1);
                                dr1["id3"] = pn.ElementAt(2);

                                dr2["id1"] = pp.ElementAt(0);
                                dr2["id2"] = pp.ElementAt(1);
                                dr2["id3"] = pp.ElementAt(2);

                                dr3["id1"] = dp.ElementAt(0);
                                dr3["id2"] = dp.ElementAt(1);
                                dr3["id3"] = dp.ElementAt(2);



                                dr4["id1"] = pic.ElementAt(0);
                                dr4["id2"] = pic.ElementAt(1);
                                dr4["id3"] = pic.ElementAt(2);

                                tb.Rows.Add(dr4);
                                tb.Rows.Add(dr1);
                                tb.Rows.Add(dr2);
                                tb.Rows.Add(dr3);

                                pn.Clear();
                                pp.Clear();
                                dp.Clear();
                                pic.Clear();
                            }

                        }
                        GridView1.DataSource = tb;
                        GridView1.DataBind();

                    }



        }

    }



}
```

Can anyone tell me how can i show the actual image. I also tried the "servermapmathod" and the following method

```
Image i1=new Image();  i1.ImageUrl=pic.ElementAt(0); dr4["id1"] =i1;
```

and in aspx file body tag's code is

```
<div>


    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="166px" Width="192px">

    </asp:GridView>

     </div>
```

Following link shows a demo that i want to obtain

[Click Here to view the demo image](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=741141162671953&set=a.259937994125608.57318.100003282296523&type=1)

But still I was unsuccessful. Please anyone help me.

Comment: You need to show your GridView markup.

Comment: how? I didn't get what you said.  I am new to asp.net.

Comment: Your ASPX page - the code on it is referred to as "markup". We need to see your markup related to the gridview, ex: `<asp:GridView runat="server"></asp:GridView` and anything inside that element.

Comment: Also, you can have the system select your data into a `DataTable` so you don't need to do it manually. Ex: `DataTable tb = new DataTable(); tb.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());`

Comment: I am basically trying to show products as in e-commerce websites in the tabular format. I am making a capstrone project for my final semester.

Comment: What version of .net are you using? If you are using 3.5 or higher, you should look into linq-to-enties, or perhaps writing stored procedures. Using linq, you can eliminate a lot extra code.

Comment: @PhilVallone It's better to learn to walk before you try to run. While that would indeed eliminate a lot, it's also important to understand what's happening underneath the hood, so sticking to ADO.NET is probably better for his/her understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using auto generated columns with your GridView. So it doesn't know it should use the path it receives to generate an HTML `img` tag. So instead of auto generated columns, we need to define them.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
  <columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="productName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="productPrice" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="discountedPrice" />
    <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlFormatString="~/{0}" DataImageUrlField="productImage" />
  </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You should also save yourself some trouble and let the framework create the data table for you.

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable(SqlCommand command, string connectionString)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
        command.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
        }
    return dt;
}

private void getdata()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select productName, productPrice, discountedPrice, productImage from Product");       
    var dt = GetDataTable(cmd, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();      
}
```

Notice how much code I eliminated? I'm assuming the values for `productImage` look something like `Images/bicycle.jpg` since you haven't described their format.

Further improvements you could make: put `GetDataTable()` in a static class somewhere, probably in `~/App_Code/DatabaseHelpers.cs` or in its own class library. You should also follow the C# naming conventions, so `getdata()` should be `GetData()`. And lastly, you could switch to a more MVC-like pattern (not MVC the framework) and define your products as models, have a data layer to retrieve them. That's outside the scope of your question, but I have a [demo project](https://github.com/mason-mcglothlin/FancyStoreDemo) I've created that oddly enough also deals with products, and shows you how to retrieve them from the database, so you can go there to learn more if you're interested in having a better architecture.

Comment: But this way the images will be shown in a column. But i want to display them in row wise and below them their price. Following link shows a sample

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=741141162671953&set=a.259937994125608.57318.100003282296523&type=1

Comment: @AshishChopra I can't access that link from my present location. I'm guessing from your description that a Repeater would be more appropriate than a GridView however. You are familiar with HTML and CSS?